# How to search for questions with least X answers without SEDE?

Tags: support, search

How do I search for questions with least X answers? I want to search for questions with least 30 answers but I can't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`is:question answers:30..`

You can use `x..y` to search between `x` and `y` (inclusively).